# Visual Composer: How to allow html tags in excerpt field

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I am trying to use Post Grid element from WPBakery Page Builder. But it strips html tags when outputting excerpt in block.
How can I disable the removal of html tags?
Thank you.

Comment: excerpt filed just like content summery so not come there any html tag in it. IF you need then use any another meta filed for this.

Comment: I guess this post on WP SE will help: [Allow HTML in excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt)